# Laravel retrieve all records 20 mins from created_at time

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a command which needs to send an email to a user 20 mins after their record was created.

The command runs every minute through the `Kernel.php`

```
$allUsers = User::where('created_at' = now()->addMinutes(20))
```

The above doesnt seem to return any records.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach on this is to create a Job [queue](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues) for sending an email then use [delayed-dispatching](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#delayed-dispatching)

You can dispatch the job upon record creation or through event listener by adding something like below after record creation

```
ProcessEmail::dispatch($user)->delay(now()->addMinutes(20));
```

Here's the full steps
first run jobs migration `php artisan queue:table`

then run artisan command to create a job `php artisan make:job ProcessEmail`

then on your `App/Jobs/ProcessEmail.php` should have something like this

```
namespace App\Jobs;
///..uses here 


class ProcessEmail implements  ShouldQueue {
    //additional uses blablaba

    protected $user;
    public $tries = 3;

    
    public function __construct( $user ) {
        //assign the user as job property to access on handle
        $this->user = $user;
    }


    public function handle() {
    
        // Email proccess
        try {
            //However you run the email
            \Log::info('I run for user '. $this->user->email);
        } catch (\Throwable $exception) {     
            
            // re-attempt on failure
            if ($this->attempts() > 2) {

                // manually set the job as failed on 3rd attempt and throw some error
                throw $exception;
            }

            // release after 5 seconds to retry the job.
            $this->release(5);

            return;
        }
        
    }
    

    public function failed(\Throwable $e) {
        // Do something on failure
        \Log::info(  $e->getMessage()  );
    }

}
```

then whereever you create the record, call that jobs
`use App\Jobs\ProcessEmail;`

then on your record creation, dispatch it after user is created like below

```
$user = User::create(['.......']);
ProcessEmail::dispatch($user)->delay(now()->addMinutes(20));
```

Comment: This is a very interesting approach ... Would it be possible to make tests for this though?

Comment: @CodeSauce, yes you can, to run a basic test, just simply create a Job the creates a entry in laravel logs with 1 minute delay, dispatch it upon record creation . if you're on local envi, you can simply call and run the command ```php artisan queue:listen``` to run the laravel queues, if you on live server, you have to configure supervisord https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
    $startDate = Carbon::now()->subMinutes(21);
    $endDate = Carbon::now()->subMinutes(19);

    $allUsers = User::->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])->get();
```

Comment: This would return all users every time over 20 mins .. So they would get sent an email all the time ... It just needs to be one time 20 mins after the record was created

Comment: sorry for that. what you need is whereBetween

Comment: This is getting close ... I think its counting 21 and 19 as well

Comment: @CodeSauce Better have an additional flag column to indicate an email has been sent.

Comment: make $startdate and $enddate to exact values. current error is coused by seconds coming with now(), remove this seconds and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

In you query *=* sign only get record which exactly match with created_at. For example you create a record on date 25-06-2022 time 04:15:33.

As your command execute every minute so it will execute on 04:15:00 & 04:16:00, these will get only records that match with time and your created record is between these as **seconds** are not matching therefore it will return **Null/empty**.
To access records you must use greater-than or equal sign **>=** in your query to get any record which is created before 20 minutes.

```
     $allUsers = User::where('created_at' >= now()->addMinutes(20))
```

Use some flag to keep record of users already sent email **otherwise your code will send email to all users** created before 20 minutes either email already sent or not.